# Maven skips JUnit/Spock failed tests run with TestNG

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, spock

I've a spock test that fails to compile - one of the class fields is attempted to be created by invoking a non-existing constructor.

When `maven-surefire-plugin` tries to run this test on the CI server (jenkins) it results in an exception:

```
09:54:59  Failure in JUnit mode for class com.whatever.SomeSpec
.
Caused by: org.spockframework.util.InternalSpockError: Failed to instantiate spec
.
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
.
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: (...)
```

Instead of failing the whole build this exception is skipped and build continues. How can I fail the build in such a situation?

`pom.xml` conf:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
    <includes>
      <include>**/Test*.java</include>
      <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
      <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure it fails to compile and not just fails to run after having been compiled successfully? If there is a compile error in the `test-compile` phase in Maven, the `test` phase should never be executed at all. Furthermore, with just your prose and a POM snippet it is difficult to analyse anything here. How about an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to make the problem reproducible? You have 57k reputation and probably know how to ask questions in a way improving your chance to get a good answer. :-)

Comment: @Opal In my case I get InternalSpockError (Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException) on runtime, but the whole maven build finishes successfully. Have you found the way to make the maven build fail in the case like that?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is not supported by Spock 1.x, only JUnit4. Spock 2.x will require the JUnit Platform.